# Rails instance variables in .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a controller action like this.
itineraries_controller.rb

```
def delete_city
  @new_itinerary = params[:new_itinerary] if params[:new_itinerary].present?
  @step = params[:step]
  if @step == 'two'
    @city = City.find(params[:id])
    @delete_rec = true
  else  
    @city_item = CityItem.find(params[:id]) rescue nil
  end  
  if @city_item.present?
    @itinerary = @city_item.country_item.itinerary rescue nil
    @itinerary = Itinerary.unscoped.find(params[:data_id])
    if (@itinerary.present? and @itinerary.user_id == current_user.id) or (current_user.moderator?)
      @country_item = @city_item.country_item
      @city_item.destroy
      @country_item.update_column('city_ids', @country_item.city_items.order(:sequence).pluck(:city_id))
      @delete_rec = true
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @delete_rec && @step != 'two'
      format.js {render 'step_two.js.erb'}
    elsif @delete_rec && @step == "two"
      format.js {render 'delete_city_step_2.js.erb'}    
    else
      format.js {render :text => 'fail'}
    end
  end
end
```

And js.erb like this:

delete_city_step_2.js.erb

```
a = $('a.cityCrossBtn[for='+"<%= @city %>"+']')
li = a.closest('.token-input-token-facebook')
li.hide();
```

I am not able to find `a` element. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@city` will give you an instance of `ActiveRecord::Base` class, and I think it's something you aren't expecting in your .js.erb file. You may be wanting an attribute related to that instance like `id` or `name`, and you can accomplish that by writing the following code:

```
a = $('a.cityCrossBtn[for='+"<%= @city.id  %>"+']')
```